# How to open a pdf located in a root folder in codeigniter without downloading the file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am a newbie in codeigniter. I am working on a site that can upload and view a PDF file. I've already succeeded on the upload.

The problem is, whenever I want to view the uploaded file in the browser, it is automatically downloading. I want to view the PDF file in the browser. how can i do it?

here is the code in my **VIEW**

```
<?php
            echo '<table class  = "table table-striped">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th class="table_head">Filename</th>';
            echo '<th class="table_head">Department</th>';
            echo '<th class="table_head">Uploaded by</th>';
            echo '<th class="table_head"></th>';
            echo '</tr>';

        if(isset($tbl_uploaded) && is_array($tbl_uploaded) && count($tbl_uploaded) > 0)
        {
            foreach($tbl_uploaded as $uploaded)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $uploaded->name .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $uploaded->department .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $uploaded->uploader .'</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="'. base_url().'uploads/'.$uploaded->name .'" target="_new">View</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your browser setting.if you are using firefox just go to open menu then
option -> application then select  portable documentation format (pdf) action to set preview in firefox.

Comment: Thanks @Rakib Roni. So there is no problem with the code? I see

Comment: welcome @noel  i cant find any kind of problem.hope so it fix your problem.let me know.

Comment: you should accept the answer if you think my answer helped you @Noel

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one, I am using this code to generate a letter from my database, I am also using a codeigniter.

```
function createPDF()

{
$data['']= $this->input->post("");
$this->load->library('mpdf');
$this->load->model('');
$query = $this->'your_model'->'model_name'($data);


    if($query!=null)
    {
$hello .=' Insert your letter here
<p>' .$data->something. '</p> //fetch something from your database';

$mpdf=new mPDF('ISO-8859-1','letter', 10, 'Arial', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'P');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(base_url().'css/pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="'.base_url().'css/edrsletter.jpg"></img>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($hello);
$mpdf->SetFooter(' Sample PDF template  - {PAGENO}');
$mpdf->Output();
}
}
```